# Extension Functions cannot be used when Secure feature proccesing is set to true

Tags: java, xml, xslt, java-ee-7, xalan

Hello i am trying to implement XML transformation using XSLT(v1) in a secure manner. I am working on a Java EE 7 environment, using Wildfly 10 and an Oracle JDK 8(1.8.0_151). In order to customize the presentation of the xml to my needs i use an xsl stylesheet which references a method i created. The problem is that when i am setting security feature to TRUE i get the following exception: 
*javax.xml.transform.TransformerException* with message: 
*Use of the extension function 'xalan://com.mycompany.mypkg.easyprint.helpers.MyClass:myMethod' is not allowed when the secure processing feature is set to true*
From the other posts i read, there is a feature that needs to be configured on the TransformerFactory so i set it.

`TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
tf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
tf.setFeature("http://www.oracle.com/xml/jaxp/properties/enableExtensionFunctions", true);`

However, when i run my application i get the following exception: 
*javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Cannot set the feature 'http://www.oracle.com/xml/jaxp/properties/enableExtensionFunctions' on this TransformerFactory.*

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trust the stylesheet enough to allow calls on external Java functions, then you trust it enough that you don't need to set the SECURE_PROCESSING feature.

However, if you have no choice but to set the SECURE_PROCESSING feature, you could use the Saxon option that allows the stylesheet to call Java extensions that have been pre-registered through the processor API. This allows the stylesheet to call only those extensions that the application has explicitly authorised. This is done using the s9api API call `Processor.registerExtensionFunction()` and the Java extension must be written to this Saxon interface.

Comment: well i guess setting the feature goes beyond just prohibiting external methods. It should also adjust configuration. But the thing is that our code review tool(Sonarqube) raises a security vulnerability on this, so i need to find a workaround. I am thinking towards using a different implementation. Maybe Saxon i dont know

Comment: Sadly, the SECURE_PROCESSING feature is widely misunderstood. Anyone who thinks you're secure if you set it and insecure if you don't is completely wrong on both counts.

Comment: Maybe it is. But i think we will get out of scope. What i actually need is an impl that will give me the option to be "secure" but to allow usage of predefined custom java methods. Do you know some tool that may do the job?

Comment: What you are asking for doesn't make sense. Executing a stylesheet that calls external Java methods is insecure.

Comment: Thanks MK, this seems like a viable solution and i am now trying it out. Actually i am having an issue with namespaces. XML files i want to transform belong to custom namespaces, which i should NOT know at runtime. So the solution should be namespace agnostic. Is there any configuration option that can achieve that or is Saxon strict about this?

Comment: That sounds like a completely separate question, so please start a new thread rather than tagging it on to an existing answer as a comment.